# Index out of range exception

Tags: c#, indexoutofrangeexception

Sir i got index out of range exception in these code
Can anybody explain me where i did mistake

```
if (SelectedRowtt > -1)
{   
    dgvSItt.Rows[SelectedRowtt].Cells["Item_Code"].Value =txtItemCode.Text;
    dgvSItt.Rows[SelectedRowtt].Cells["Description"].Value = txtDescription.Text;
    dgvSItt.Rows[SelectedRowtt].Cells["Qty"].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(txtQty.Text).ToString(Program.gDigitsAfterDecimal);
    dgvSItt.Rows[SelectedRowtt].Cells["UOM"].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(txtUOM.Text).ToString(Program.gDigitsAfterDecimal);

    gvSItt.Rows[SelectedRowtt].Cells["Amount"].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(txtAmount.Text).ToString(Program.gDigitsAfterDecimal);
    dgvSItt.Rows[SelectedRowtt].Cells["Discount"].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(txtRate.Text).ToString(Program.gDigitsAfterDecimal);
    SelectedRowtt = -1;
}
else
{
    IsDO = false;
    dgvSItt.Rows.Add();
    SelectedRowtt = -1;
}
```

Comment: What is `SelectedRowtt ` ?

Comment: dgvSItt has no Rows maybe? Did you check if it has any rows in it before processing it?

Comment: The best answer to your question is: Learn to use the debugger. This is simply a matter to check what is the value of SelectedRowtt at the exception time against the number of rows in your grid

Answer (score 0):

You get that message when you have used an index on an array (or collection) that is not valid. For instance you may have an array defined for `myArray[0]` up to `myArray[10]`. If you tried to access `myArray[-1]` or `myArray[11]` you would get the error.

In your case it could be on the rows or the cells collections.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you get `SelectedRowtt`.
Usualy such exception happens because indexes start with 0 and end with `Rows.Count -1` and you try to get `dgvSItt.Rows[Rows.Count]`.